# results.next() == false and there's no printing of data

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

results.next() is false, !results.next() in the while loop prints ResultSet closed

I've tried EVERYTHING. from doing Class.forName() to connection.setAutoCommit(false) nothing's working :/

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       String query = "SELECT * FROM StudentInfo";
       String url;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            results = ps.executeQuery();
            while (results.next()) {
               print(results.getString("nameID"));
            }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        print(e.getMessage());
    }
```

}

just prints out BUILD SUCCESSFUL without printing any of my data

Comment: Are there any records in the `StudentInfo` table..?

Comment: yes- there's 20 data sets in nameID, which is the first column in StudentInfo

Comment: at least add a `System.out.println("starting");` or  `System.out.println("done");` (Hint: if you are catching an Exception , always print the stack trace `e.printStackTrace();`)

Comment: BTW: `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` comes when building/compiling, not necessarily when starting/running - so, are you sure starting the program or *only* building it? (maybe describe how you are trying it)

Comment: I did that within the try {, everything seems to be fine until I execute resultSet. Could there be a potential problem with executeQuery?

Comment: or try something weird `SELECT * FROM StudentInfoERROR`

Comment: I might be only building it, thank you for pointing that out :) what exactly do you mean by starting the program?

Comment: 1) compiling/building - parse the Java code and create a bytecode file (*.class) - e.g. command line `javac Classname.java`  2 ) starting/executing - read that *.class fie(s) and execute its bytecode - command line `java Classname`

Comment: just tried StudentInfoERROR, does not contain the table :/

Comment: so it is running and connecting to the database... then somehow that table is empty (different user, schema, ...), maybe try `SELECT count(*) ...` and `results.getInt(1)` (despite missing `url` values and `results` declaration, posted code seems OK)

Comment: i did SELECT count(*) FROM StudentInfo and results.getInt(1)...interestingly the output is now 0

Comment: If the output is zero then you are not connected to the same database that contains 20 entries. What is the value of URL? "jdbc:sqlite:ProjectWeekDB.sqlite"? What client is checking for the 20 rows? Try executing the count operation in that client also, instead of using any viewer it provides.

Comment: how exactly do you execute the count operation in that client?

Comment: Or you sure that the application uses the same database as the one that you think contains those records?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to consider is to make sure that the table isn't empty.

`Class.forName` isn't even assigned to anything. 
`connection.setAutoCommit(false)` is irrelevant here as that's more of a transaction detail. You don't need to worry about that for a query this simple.

I'd try running a query that you know works first. Maybe your connection isn't even correct or possibly null, thus never really executing the query. That's probably why your resultset is closed.

I also hope `print()` is `from System.out` or something that will actually print.

Comment: print() is System.out, yes. and no, my connection is not null (i used an if statement to check)

Comment: also my url is "jdbc:sqlite:ProjectWeekDB.sqlite"

Comment: wrong,  *The first thing to consider* is if the program is starting   [:-)